# Does the throw new error act as a return in Javascript- Question

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if someone could explain to me why the code below does not log the users email but skips it entirely:

```
let getUser = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const user = { 
        name: 'John Doe', 
        email: 'jdoe@email.com', 
        permissions: [ 'db', 'hr', 'dev']
    };
    resolve(user);
});

getUser
.then(function(user) {
    console.log(`Got user ${user.name}`);
    if(user.permissions.includes('hr')){
        throw new Error('You are not allowed to access the HR module.');
    }
     return user.email;
})
.then(function(email) {
   console.log(`User email is ${email}`);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error)
});
```

the code prints out:

```html
Got user John Doe
Error: You are not allowed to access the HR module.
```

Does the throw new error act as a return? Meaning if the if condition is true the function does not even reach the return email line at all as it has already returned with the error?

With that said - if this is the case then does that also mean that `.then(function(email){ })` is just skipped? And does then it move onto the `catch`?

Comment: Throwing an error there ends the callback immediately, so it never returns the email. It also rejects the promise, so the next then callback isn't invoked at all. It's not a return _in general_ because, unlike a return, a throw can be caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

> The **`throw` statement** throws a user-defined exception. Execution of the current function will stop (the statements after `throw` won't be executed), and control will be passed to the first [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block in the call stack. If no `catch` block exists among caller functions, the program will terminate.
>
> [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

Answer (score 0):

### Answers

> Does the throw new error act as a return?

Yes

> if the if condition is true the function does not even reach the return email line at all as it has already returned with the error?

Yes

### Example

```js
const throwError = value => {
  if (value) throw 'some error'
  return 'actual value'
}

try {
  console.log('without throw =', throwError(false))
  console.log('with throw =', throwError(true))
} catch (error) {
  console.log('caught =', error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code of a promise executor and promise handlers has an "invisible try..catch " around it. If an exception happens, it gets caught and treated as a rejection. For instance, this code: new Promise((resolve, reject) => { throw new Error("Whoops!"); }).catch(alert); // Error: Whoops! …Works exactly the same as this:

Once got rejected there is no point of executing other lines of code and second then will not get executed as first one was rejected.

[Source](https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling)